# Making an audio equalizer video

Tags: audio, video, video-capture, equalizer

I need to make a video of an audio equalizer.

So i need a script that analyses audio every frame, and extracts the frequency apectrum so i can draw that somehow and make an equalizer.

The first part of the problem is easily solvable on frontend as there is a myriad of open source equalizer visualisations in canvas.

The thing works nicely in browser but i have a problem to make an mp4 of that.

Ive tried using headless browsers(pupeteer and phantomjs) to capture frames from canvas, but i could not get the framerate above 10fps, resulting in unacceptable video quality and sync issues when connecting the jpg frames and mp3 via ffmpeg. The plan was to speed it up, so you dont have to wait for the full audio length to finish to get an mp4, but i cant even get it to show above 10fps on regular playback speed.

I feel the tech i thought would work is not there yet, and i might be in need of a different approach.

The only condition is that it has to run as a script on a linux server. So any programmimg language or any equalizer design will work.

Any ideas or resources are more than welcome. Thanks

Comment: [Processing?](https://processing.org/)

Comment: I was hoping for a more straight forward approach, if i have to rewrite everything from scratch there are many libs that i could use. But thanks :)

Comment: There are some visualisation sketches in the examples I believe, so you wouldn't even need to write anything, unless you wanted something bespoke. All you need to do is probably add `fullScreen()` instead of `size(,)`